# Excel Pivot Table IF Statement

Tags: excel, excel-pivot

What I'm trying to do is, I have on the sheet of multiple dates (report dates) in column A and a transition date column in column E. From B - D I have numbers in each column corresponding with actual price then fees. What happens in this is sheet is reports come in and get transitioned on a specific date and switches fees from Column C (Before Transition Date) to Column D (After Transition Date). What I want to do with the Pivot table is this:
I want to be able to add column B & C but when the item hits the transition date to switch over to adding B & D and continues the SUM of it all. My thought process is it would have to do a IF statement, something along the lines of

```
IF(Transition Date >= Date, Add B & C, IF(Transition Date <= Date, Add B & D),0)
```

But I could be wrong, just trying to figure this part out on a Pivot Table. Again I am new with Pivot Tables so if my terminology is incorrect please correct me.

Comment: Image of your data with headers and desired outcome would help

Comment: =IF(A2<E2,SUM(B2:C2),SUM(B2,D2))

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/4TicU)

This is what a sample of it looks like. The numbers do vary from column to column. Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Hi, Edit link into question so others can find it easily. I have given a non-pivottable option above in comments (you would drag this formula down) and a pivottable option below as answer. Try those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i have understood you correctly you want to add a calculated field to your pivot.

Say your data looked like this Range("A1:E4") in image:

[image: Image of data and pivot]

You would add a calculated field to the pivot (Starting row 13 in image) using the following formula:

```
=IF(Date < TransitionDate, Cost + 'Ore Fee', Cost + 'Mineral Fee')
```

This equates to:

```
=IF(ReportDate < TransitionDate, ColB + BeforeTransitionDate, ColB + AfterTransitionDate)
```

Your mileage on layout may vary as i am using an old mac which is not ideal for pivottables and i have hidden some irrelevant pivot fields.

Windows machine i think you add a calculated field by selecting a cell inside the pivot, the going to Analyze -> Fields, Items, & Sets -> click the little down arrow -> Calculated Field. Example [here](http://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-calculated-field.html)

Layout of pivot:

[image: Approximate pivottable layout (using Mac)]

Where to enter calculated field:

[image: Calculated field]

And comparing with in sheet formulas without pivottable see Column H rows 14:16 (formula i gave from the comments):

[image: Comparing pivot with in sheet formulas]

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no need for a PivotTable here, as you can create an additional column (say, `ActualPrice`) that conditions on summing columbs B & D or C & D:

[image]

In the above example, `TransactionDate` and `TransitionDate` were made with `=DATE(2017,12,randbetween(1,31))`, with conditional formatting highlighting the `TransactionDates` that are on-or-after/before `TransitionDate` in red/green. The `ActualPrice` is calculated as `=IF(A2<E2,B2,C2)+D2`.

If you want you can create a PivotTable to aggregate all of this, or just return the total sum in some cell (outside Column F) as `=SUM(F:F)`.